# Generate MQsql query to get records

Tags: mysql

I am having the following table say "A"

```
"column1"   "column2"
   1         arafath@gmail.com
   2         ram@gmail.com;arafath@gmail.com
   3         tom@gmail.com
```

I want to get the records with the following condition.

Condition1: 
      If the column value exist in the any of the row, it will retrieve the matched rows

Condition2:
      If the column value doesn't match with any of the row, it wants to retrieve all the rows

```
  Eg: column2 = "ram@gmail.com"
  Output should be "row 2"

  Eg: column2 = "arafath@gmail.com"
  Output should be "row 1, row 2"

  Eg: column2 = "xxx@gmail.com" (Unmatched column)
  Output should be all the rows (row 1, row 2, row 3)
```

Please help me out to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below one.

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM yourTable 
where ( not exists (Select col2
FROM yourTable where col2 like 'xxx@gmail.com') 
or col2 like 'xxx@gmail.com');
```

Comment: Please, can you extend your answer with more detailed explanation? This will be very useful for understanding. Thank you!

Comment: The inner select statement will check whether any record is available in the table. If yes, then the not exists keyword will make the condition false and execute the second part. If the where condition become true, then the entire table will be retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

We can try using a union here:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM yourTable
WHERE col2 REGEXP '[[:<:]]ram@gmail.com[[:>:]]'
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2
FROM yourTable
WHERE col2 NOT REGEXP '[[:<:]]ram@gmail.com[[:>:]]' AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable WHERE col2 REGEXP '[[:<:]]ram@gmail.com[[:>:]]');
```

### Demo

The above strategy is that the first half of the union returns the matching record, if it exists.  The second half of the union then returns all other records, but only if on match were found in the first half of the union.  If a match *were* found, then the `WHERE` clause in the second half of the union would fail, and would return nothing.

Also, please note that storing comma separated (or semicolon separated) data in your MySQL tables is generally bad practice.  I had to use `REGEXP` to get around this problem, but ideally if each email had a separate row, we would only need to use `=` equality.